# Creating wallets with bitcoinj and public key/address

Tags: java, bitcoinj

I am new to Bitcoin and bitcoinj and would like to create 2 wallets and exchange some bitcoins among them. I went trough the tutorial on how to create a WalletAppKit using bitcoinj and I managed to create 2 wallets and transfer some test coins among them.

But now my question is, if I have an exchange where a user just enters his address, how can I create the wallet from the address (either from addr:mgXJZSEVQTKMzoCbJoNYVWX4nZezKXuyvs or pub:038917e1b307f84cfc85d359ea4e6036671fa5810e8b717af6a676c99b13241a28 timestamp:1402905638), check the balance and send then some coins?

I couldn't figure out how to create a wallet without the WalletAppKit. I asked at the Google Group but they are not very supportive for absolute beginners.